# Examples of rvalue, lvalues, xvalues, glvalues, and prvalues?

Tags: c++, rvalue, lvalue, xvalue, prvalue

This post [What are rvalues, lvalues, xvalues, glvalues, and prvalues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601602/what-are-rvalues-lvalues-xvalues-glvalues-and-prvalues?noredirect=1&lq=1) provides the definitions of rvalue, lvalues, xvalues, glvalues, and prvalues, but I don't see examples.

I think I have a solid understanding of lvalues and rvalues, but not so much of xvalues, glvalues, and prvalues. Examples (code) of each and their differentiation would really help.

Comment: The cppreference seems to have exhaustive examples: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category

Comment: A good graphical approach is given in this [ACCU link](https://accu.org/index.php/journals/2641) of an article of the free [Overload Journal 150](https://accu.org/var/uploads/journals/Overload150.pdf)

Comment: The question has already an answer [in this Stack Overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601602/what-are-rvalues-lvalues-xvalues-glvalues-and-prvalues).